# Flutter> Patrol > Mobile automatization test: How to access to "Subscribe" button on system pop-up Google Play Store?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol, flutter-native-view

I'm trying to purchase a subscription in my tests. Everything goes well until the native Android purchase popup appears. I'm not able to tap on the green 'Subscribe' button. Is there a way to do it? The following code doesn't work:

**    [See screenshot - which button is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDv2w.png) **

```
void main() async { 
  group('App', ()   {

    patrolTest('Buy Subscription', nativeAutomation: true, ( PatrolTester tester) async {

      await app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await tester(ElevatedButton).tap();
      await tester.native.tap(Selector(text: 'Subscribe'));    });}); }
```

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Question needs edit, I tried but couldn't

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [take a view hierarchy dump](https://patrol.leancode.co/tips-and-tricks#inspecting-native-view-hierarchy) while you see the "Subscribe" button on-screen (you mustn't to do it while the test is running):

```
adb shell uiautomator dump && adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml .
```

Then open the `window_dump.xml` file in some code editor, CTRL+F for "Subscription" and see if the button is visible there. Maybe the `text` attribute is not set, but `contentDescription` is? So you could try doing:

```dart
await tester.native.tap(Selector(contentDescription: 'Subscribe'));
```

Comment: Thanks!  

Dump for subscribe:  

 
```<node index="0" text="Subscribe" resource-id="com.android.vending:id/0_resource_name_obfuscated" class="android.widget.Button" package="com.android.vending" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[72,2106][1008,2164]" /></node>```  

 I tried such a solution, but no success:  
```'await tester.native.tap(Selector(pkg:'com.android.vending',className: 'android.widget.Button'));'```

Comment: Currently, I updated to Patrol 2.0.0, and unfortunately I have a problem with new file test_bundle.dart it looks like import my test files doesn't work correctly.  
I back to the topic when I will be able to fix this.

Comment: That's sad to hear. Feel free to create an issue on GitHub, I'll do my best to help.

Comment: on GitHub #1492. Thank you for help!